# PouchDB error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: doc is undefined"

Tags: pouchdb

I am always get this error, but only with Firefox – with Chrome it works.

I only have copied the demo code from the PouchDB website.

```
var db = new PouchDB('todos');
var remoteCouch = false;

db.changes({
  since: 'now',
  live: true
}).on('change', showTodos);

function addTodo(text) {
  var todo = {
    _id: new Date().toISOString(),
    title: text,
    completed: false
  };
  db.put(todo, function callback(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Successfully posted a todo!');
    }
  });
}

function showTodos() {
  db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, doc) {
    redrawTodosUI(doc.rows);
  });
}
```

Have anyone an idea why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the code that creates the `db`? If you provided a minimally complete example that reproduces the error, an answer would be forthcoming.

Comment: I've updated my post. As described I am using the example code from the PouchDB website. > https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html

Comment: What pouchdb version and which adapter are you using?

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.3.0/dist/pouchdb.min.js without adapter and also tested with HTTP (CouchDB). And now another error occurs: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations. But I am not using private browsing.